# installing the "bivpois" package in R using Windows

Tags: r, windows, installation, package

I have to install the `"bivpois"` package in the software R using Windows.
Browsing on the Internet on StackOverflow site, I found different solution to my problem, but I cannot to solve that.

The R version is the 3.1.2

I tried to install this package, as suggested by some on SO and on the Internet, running the following lines:

1. Using a zip file;

   install.packages('FILE_LOCATION',repos=NULL,type="source")
2. Using the code file

   install.packages('FILE_LOCATION',repos=NULL,type="source")
3. Using the link of the website where one can download the package:

   install.packages("bivpois", repos = "http://stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jbn/papers/paper14.htm",type = "source")

The last 3 way give an error as output, while running "Install package from local zip file" allows to install properly (apparently) the package.
When I want to call the package after installed, using `library()`R gives the following error:

```
Error: package ‘bivpois’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

and updating by running `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)` does not help to call the package.

How can I install this package and call it?
Can it be not supported anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running on a Mac but I cannot see that my method would not succeed as well on a PC as long as you understand how to view and rename hidden files. I didn't figure that I'd be able to fix the package problem, so I took the authors up on their offer to download the [zipped `.Rdata` file](http://stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jbn/papers/files/14/14_bivpois_RDATA.zip) that had the functions in it. I unzipped it (erroneously thinking it would be named '14_bivpois_RDATA' but discovered that it was named '.Rdata' when expanded in my /Downloads/ folder. Dot-files are hidden in the file-browsers by default on Macs and Windows machines but I run my Mac with these files visible. So I renamed it `bivpois.RData` making it visible and preventing it from over-writing my .Rdata file in my working directory. I then closed out my session and double-clicked on `bivpois.RData` and the functions, `pbivpois`, `bivpois.table`, `lm.bp`, `lm.dibp` `simple.bp` and `splitbeta` seem to be loaded.

The other way to do this would be to expand the source and separately `source` the `.R` files in it:

[image]

Comment: I will try to do as you suggested in your answer. Thanks for the help @BondedDust